# Custom URL for ShowButton on admin-on-rest

Tags: admin-on-rest

Does it have any way to make a custom path for some Show buttons?

I have a `ReferecenManyField` that has 2 types of components underneath and I want to redirect to the Show page of each of these components.

In my `CollectionShow` I have

```
<Show title={<CollectionTitle />} actions={<CollectionShowActions />} {...props}>
  <SimpleShowLayout>
  ...

  <ReferenceManyField label="Itens" target="collection_id" reference="collection_items">
    <Datagrid bodyOptions={{ showRowHover: true }}>
       <TextField source="id" />
       <TextField label="Tipo" source="collectionable_type" />
       <TextField label="Nome" source="collectionable.name" sortable={false} />
       <TextField label="Privacidade" source="collectionable.privacy" sortable={false} />
       <ShowButton />
    </Datagrid>
  </ReferenceManyField>
```

... where my `collectionable_type` can be either another Collection or a LearningObject.

**Is there any way to make a customable URL for the `ShowButton`?**

Maybe something like:

```
<ShowButton basePath={"/${collectionable_type}/${collectionable.id}"} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<ShowButton />` component is dedicated to creating links to a show view managed by admin-on-rest.

To make a customable URL in your `Datagrid`, you should create a dedicated `field component` as explained in the documentation [Writing Your Own Field Component](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component)